# How do I remove quotes from tuples and then store them as a tuple

Tags: python, mysql, list, parameters, tuples

So i am trying to make a SQL Statement which needs to print the data in the order I specify. But I need to this for more than two tuples so I tried to make a function for it.I was able to get the column names from the information_schema table and stored them as a tuple.So I stored them as a list like below:

```
get="Select %s,%s,%s from table"
tup=['ID', 'Name', 'Work']
Cursor.execute(get,tuple(tup))
for i in Cursor:
  print(i)
```

But when I ran this, I found out that the elements from list were going along with the quotes which then just printed the column names.I tried to remove them by using the code below but was still getting errors:

```
get="Select %s,%s,%s from table"
tup=['ID', 'Name', 'Work']
tup2=tup[0]+","+tup[1]+","+tup[2]
Cursor.execute(get,tuple(tup2,))
for i in Cursor:
    print(i)
```

The above code was showing not enough parameters error.
Please give any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass column names as query parameters. The mechanism that parameterized query provides is meant to pass literal values from your code to the query, not meta-information such as column names.

What you want actually requires string concatenation:

```
tup=['ID', 'Name', 'Work']
get = "select " + tup[0] + "," + tup[1], "," + tup[2] + " from table"
Cursor.execute(get)
for i in Cursor:
    print(i)
```

Or:

```
get = "select " + ','.join(tup) + " from table"
```

Be aware that this code exposes you to SQL injection (if some malicious string is part of the list, bad things might happen). Be sure to propery validate the content of the list if it comes from outside your code.

Comment: I want the list to form from the information_schema database, so how do I validate it's content? Thank you for your advice! : D